# I need to print out the 4 largest values and sum them up in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My code only prints the largest one, but I need to have the 4 largest numbers displayed and to be summed up.

```js
let sizes = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
let largest = sizes[0];

for (let x = 0; x < sizes.length; x++) {
    if (largest < sizes[x] ) {
        largest = sizes[x];
    }
}
console.log(largest);;
```

Comment: There are many ways to print 4 largest numbers. You can sort the list and then print the last 4 elements or use 4 variables. There are many other ways to do this.

Comment: Hint: sort the array. If you don't want modify the input array,  slice the input array from zero and sort the slice. I assume this is homework - search [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for information on `Array.prototype.slice` and `Array.prototype.sort` if you havn't used them before.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this code.

```js
let sizes = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
sizes.sort(function(a, b) { return b - a });
console.log(sizes.slice(0, 4).join(' '));
console.log(sizes.slice(0, 4).reduce((total, num) => total + num));
```

Comment: that worked, how can make 5 inputs and the biggest number to be in the middle like:

Input: 41352
Output: 41523

Please help

Comment: Please use this code.
let sizes = [4,1,3,5,2];
const max = Math.max(...sizes);
sizes = sizes.filter(val => val != max);
sizes.splice(sizes.length/2, 0, max);
console.log(sizes);

Comment: Almost work but the output is: [4, 1, 5, 3, 2]

It has to be:  [4, 1, 5, 2, 3]

Comment: let sizes = [4,1,3,5,2];
const max = Math.max(...sizes);
sizes = sizes.filter(val => val != max);
const rest = sizes.splice(sizes.length/2, sizes.length - sizes.length/2, max);
sizes = sizes.concat(rest.sort((a,b) => (a-b)));
console.log(sizes);

Is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

One method you can use is to sort your elements first, and then simply print out the first 4 elements:

```
sizes(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(sizes[0])
console.log(sizes[1])
console.log(sizes[2])
console.log(sizes[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that...

```js
const 
  sizes   = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32]
, sumLargest = sizes.reduce((lg,x)=>
    {
    if (lg.length < 4) lg.push(x)
    else
      {
      let min = Math.min(...lg)
      if (x>min) lg[lg.indexOf(min)] = x
      }  
    return lg
    },[]).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)

console.log('sumLargest = ', JSON.stringify(sumLargest ))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are easy solutions (sorting the array `O(n log(n))`) and there are performant solutions (`O(n)`) like:

```js
let sizes = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
let largest = sizes.slice(0, 4).sort((lhs, rhs) => rhs - lhs);

for (let x = 4; x < sizes.length; x++) {
    if (largest[3] < sizes[x]) {
        largest[3] = sizes[x];
        largest = largest.sort((lhs, rhs) => rhs - lhs);
    }
}
console.log(largest);
```